# How to package a few Java files for coding challenge?

Tags: java, email, compression, package

I'm completely new to Java and was sent a Java coding challenge which I completed along with JUnit tests that all run on my local machine.

It's only a few files and looks something like this:

```
- README.md
- class1.java
- program.java
- programRunner.java
- tests
    - Test.java
    - TestRunner.java
```

I'm on osx, used SublimeText for my IDE and run everything through Terminal (including the JUnit tests which means I had to set my $CLASSPATH to point to where JUnit and Hamcrest JAR files are on my machine).

What is the most appropriate way to package and compress these files to send via email in a single file so that the person opening can easily run my program and tests?

Comment: I would suggest using maven http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Maybe just zip it and include a batch/bash file to compile and run it? Usually when I work directly from command line, I write a quick script that runs the code anyway